# XY data in sketch properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, xy, text

Does anyone know if there is a way to export the xy data from sketch properties in the editor to a .txt file?

Comment: Could you please specify which software are you using and add appropriate tags. Also what type of feature class are you editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch properties represent geometry coordinates of a feature.
In ArcGIS environment, you can access (print, store to txt files,..) geometry properties by:

```
import arcpy

infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Enter for loop for each feature
#
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    # Print the current multipoint's ID
    #
    print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))
    partnum = 0

    # Step through each part of the feature
    #
    for part in row[1]:
        # Print the part number
        #
        print("Part {0}:".format(partnum))

        # Step through each vertex in the feature
        #
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                # Print x,y coordinates of current point
                #
                print("{0}, {1}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
            else:
                # If pnt is None, this represents an interior ring
                #
                print("Interior Ring:")
        partnum += 1
```

See more info at [reading geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000).

Comment: This will work.  I've been trying to find the code to limit the number of decimal places in the lat/lon.  I only need 4 which I specified to be displayed in ArcMap but this script brings up to 8.

Comment: to limit decimal points, use python round function: i.e.: print("{0}, {1}".format(round(pnt.X, 4), round(pnt.Y,4)))

Comment: I hate to tell you @Matej, but this is **wrong**. Python will only give you the feature *as it is stored in the database* not *as it has been modified during a sketch* the only way to get to the sketch is with IEditSketch http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEditSketch_Interface/0020000000wm000000/ which is an ArcObjects interface. It is possible that it is available in the ArcPy add-in interface but I can't find a reference to it.